# Why is the entropy of container A the greatest?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

#### Question

> **9.35** Container **A** is filled with 1.0 mol of the atoms of an ideal monatomic gas. Container **B** has 1.0 mol of atoms bound together as diatomic molecules that are not vibrationally active. Container **C** has 1.0 mol of atoms bound together as diatomic molecules that are vibrationally active. The containers
>   all start at $T_\mathrm{i}$ and the temperature is increased to $T_\mathrm{f}.$ Rank the containers in order of increasing change in entropy. Explain
>   your reasoning.

### Answer

> **B** < **C** < **A**

#### My Approach

I thought that you were supposed to assume that container **C** had the most number of atoms and therefore a greater entropy automatically.

Answer (score 2):

An accurate summary of the relative molar heat capacities of the different species is given in another answer and recapitulated in the following table together with the total heat capacity for each gas:

$$\begin{array}{|case|Cv|} \hline \textrm{molecule} & C_{vm}/R & NC_{vm}/R \\ \hline  \mathrm{A} & 3/2 & 1.5 \\ \mathrm{B} & 5/2 & 1.25  \\\mathrm{C} & 7/2 & 1.75 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

where $N$ is the total *amount of gas*, which based on the problem described in the OP is either $\pu{1 mol}$ of atoms ($\mathrm{A}$) or $\pu{\frac{1}{2} mol}$ of homonuclear diatomic molecules ($\mathrm{B}$ and $\mathrm{C}$).

Since the entropy change for the isochoric temperature change is $\Delta S = C_v \log\left( \frac{T_2}{T_1} \right)$, it follows that $\Delta S_C > \Delta S_A > \Delta S_B$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathrm{A}$, the atoms are only increasing their internal energy by the three degrees of liberty due to translation. There are no rotation $n_i$ vibration. So $C_v = 3/2 R$

In $\mathrm{B}$, there is two degrees of liberty due to rotation. This makes twice $R/2$ to add to the precedent values. $C_v = 5R/2$.

In $\mathrm{C}$, there is two new degrees of liberty due to vibration which increases potential and kinetics energy. This makes a supplement of $2 \cdot R/2 = R$, which has to be added to the precedent values, $C_v = 7R/2$.

For a given change of temperature, more energy $\Delta Q$ has to be given to the gas when changing from $\mathrm{A}$ to $\mathrm{B}$ to $\mathrm{C}$.

As $dS = dQ/T$, the change of entropy follows the same order. So $\mathrm{C}$ has had a greater change of entropy than $\mathrm{B}$ and of course than $\mathrm{A}$.

Comment: The important detail is the molar amount of atoms, so B and C contain a half molar amount of substance, compared to A.